# Best Jenkins Plugins for Coding Standard Validation against build ( For .NET )

Tags: jenkins, coding-style, jenkins-plugins, devops, code-standards

I am looking for something which will automatically validate the coding standards in Jenkins. I have seen some plugins for that like OSWAP Dependency check, CheckStyle, Dry, Findbugs, Violations (Fxcop, Stylecop), Warning etc. All projects are made in dotNet.

Can someone tell me which are the best and mandatory plugins/checks that should be added and checked?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some plugins that i find very useful:

- sonarqube, works well with .NET
- Official OWASP ZAP, security scanner
- warning plugin

All depends on your requirements.